# using unreal engine to collect random objects in a sequence

Tags: arrays, sequence

I'm using the unreal engine but my question relates to any code or game engine. I want the player to collect 5 random objects and the random objects must be collected in a particular sequence or order. I imagine the lazy way is to do a true/false condition for each trigger, but I imagine that would get messy if I needed to add extra objects to the sequence etc. What is the correct way of structuring the code for what I'm after? Should an if statement be linked in with an array somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could make a master list where every collectible item is sorted in order. Then you can simply run through that list for every item that you have.

For example:

```
masterList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
collection = {...}

*masterPos = 0 //Updated inside the function
for i over collection
    if(!findMatch(masterPos, masterList[i]))
        return false
end for
return true
```

This way you will check for each element being in the master array and if they are not in the desired order then the findMatch will fail since one of the previous searches set the masterPos to a greater value than the index of the item you search for.

Example:
collection = {2, 5, 6}
After one search (2) the masterPos value is 2. Then it becomes 5 and finally 6.

If we instead look at a list that is NOT in order, then we get the following result:
collection = {5, 6, 2}
After the first search the masterPos value is 5. Next search gives it the value of 6, then, since we start at the last position, we finish the entire list without finding 2 so we return false.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Noobs DeSroobs. I found this solution on the Unreal Forum - this worked for me: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/314105/how-to-see-if-a-series-of-triggers-has-been-activa.html